# Why with several dynamic checkboxes event is not triggered?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In Laravel 10/ livewire 3 / tailwindcss 3 app I need to make several dynamic checkboxes, where user can select several elements and I defined in a component:

```
namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Enums\ReactionActionEnum;
use App\Enums\AppImageUsedInSubscriptionEnum;
use Livewire\Component;

class UserReaction extends Component
{
    public int $id;
    public string $dataType;
    public array $reactionActions = [];

    public function mount(int $id, string $dataType)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->dataType = $dataType;


        $reactionActions = ReactionActionEnum::getSelectionItems();
        $this->reactionActions = [];
        foreach ($reactionActions as $key => $label)
            $this->reactionActions[] = [
                'key' => $key,
                'label' => $label,
                'checked' => false,
            ];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user-reaction');
    }

    public function updated($key, $value)
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($key, ' -1 updated $key::'));    // THIS METHOD IS NOT EVEN CALLED
        \Log::info(varDump($value, ' -1 updated $value::'));
    }
}
```

and in blade file :

```
$reactionActions:: {{ print_r($reactionActions, true) }}

@foreach($reactionActions as $reactionAction)
    <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in">
        <label for="reaction_actions">{{ $reactionAction['label'] }}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model="reactionActions.{{ $reactionAction['key'] }}" name="reaction_actions" value="{{ $reactionAction['key'] }}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I expected when checkbox is clicked checked property of $reactionAction array would be changed and/or updated method would be raised. But this did not happen.

How can I make it working ?

**UPDATED CODE :**

$reactionActions var is created based on enum :

```
$reactionActions = ReactionActionEnum::getSelectionItems();
$this->reactionActions = [];

foreach ($reactionActions as $key => $label)
    $this->reactionActions[] = [
        'key' => $key,
        'label' => $label,
        'checked' => false,
    ];
    \Log::info(varDump($this->reactionActions, ' -1 $this->reactionActions::'));
```

ande checking debug  info I see that checked rendered as empty string(boll type is lost >) :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1
            [label] => Like
            [checked] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => 2
            [label] => Love
            [checked] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => 3
            [label] => Dislike
            [checked] =>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key] => 4
            [label] => Hate
            [checked] =>
        )
```

In I used ".live" : I got different error :

[image]

The same error with uncommented label

I am not sure if I need to use "checked" key in :

```
<input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="reactionActions.{{ $reactionAction['checked'] }}" name="reaction_actions" value="{{ $reactionAction['key'] }}">
```

But I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Livewire 3 *wire:model* is deferred by default. To allow a contextual response you can use instead *wire:model.live*

To let the loop work properly, a *wire:key* valued with an unique key is also needed, otherwise the view could be updated in an inconsistent way. In my example I use *$reactionAction['key']* supposing that it's a unique value, if not you must choose a different value, e.g. a record *id*

```html
@foreach($reactionActions as $reactionAction)

    <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in" 
         wire:key="{{ $reactionAction['key'] }}"
    >

        <label>

            {{ $reactionAction['label'] }}

            <input type="checkbox" 
                   wire:model.live="reactionActions.{{ $reactionAction['key'] }}"
                   name="reaction_actions" 
                   value="{{ $reactionAction['key'] }}"
            >

        </label>

    </div>

@endforeach
```

Here I have also fixed the labels
Note that your *wire:model* value could be not properly set: take a look [here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/wire-model#multiple-checkboxes) for the details

#### Edit after question updates

The fact that clicking on a checkbox a call to the backend is made, means that now the event is intercepted.

As already suggested, the way you reference the checkboxes is not properly set, that is the cause of the error.
If you want to maintain your data structure, you can consider evaluating each checkbox as a checkbox in its own right, so the view portion will become:

```html
 @foreach($reactionActions as $index => $reactionAction)

        <div class="some-classes" wire:key="actions-{{$reactionAction['key']}}">

            <label>

                {{ $reactionAction['label']}}

                <input type="checkbox"
                       wire:model.live="reactionActions.{{$index}}.checked" {{-- NOTE THIS --}}
                >

            </label>

        </div>

    @endforeach
```

Also the output that you are showing is generated by *print_r* which outputs *false* and *null* values as empty strings (like *echo* does), if you want to see those values printed, you can use *var_export()*.

I don't know where your *varDump()* function comes from, anyway a working *updated()* method to log the changes can be:

```php
public function updated($varName, $value)
{
    Log::info("key: $varName");
    Log::info("value: $value (" . var_export($value, true) . ')');
}
```

Comment: Please read UPDATED CODE

Comment: The fact that clicking on a checkbox a calls the backend is made, means that the event is intercepted, as requested in the title.
In my answer I already suggested that the way you reference the checkboxes is not properly set.
Also note that the bool type is not lost, the output that you are showing is generated by *print_r* which outputs *false* and *null* values as empty strings (like *echo* does), if you want to see those values printed , you can use *var_export()*.
See my addition to my answer for details